# Problem when converting 'Fermat's primality test' from a Java to Python

Tags: java, python, primes

I took the following program from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/primality-test-set-2-fermet-method/),

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.math.*; 

class GFG { 

    /* Iterative Function to calculate 
    // (a^n)%p in O(logy) */
    static int power(int a,int n, int p) 
    { 
        // Initialize result 
        int res = 1; 

        // Update 'a' if 'a' >= p 
        a = a % p;  

        while (n > 0) 
        { 
            // If n is odd, multiply 'a' with result 
            if ((n & 1) == 1) 
                res = (res * a) % p; 

            // n must be even now 
            n = n >> 1; // n = n/2 
            a = (a * a) % p; 
        } 
        return res; 
    } 

    // If n is prime, then always returns true,  
    // If n is composite than returns false with  
    // high probability Higher value of k increases 
    //  probability of correct result. 
    static boolean isPrime(int n, int k) 
    { 
    // Corner cases 
    if (n <= 1 || n == 4) return false; 
    if (n <= 3) return true; 

    // Try k times 
    while (k > 0) 
    { 
        // Pick a random number in [2..n-2]      
        // Above corner cases make sure that n > 4 
        int a = 2 + (int)(Math.random() % (n - 4));  

        // Fermat's little theorem 
        if (power(a, n - 1, n) != 1) 
            return false; 

        k--; 
        } 

        return true; 
    } 

    // Driver Program  
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        int k = 3; 
        if(isPrime(11, k)) 
            System.out.println(" true"); 
        else
            System.out.println(" false"); 
        if(isPrime(15, k)) 
            System.out.println(" true"); 
        else
            System.out.println(" false"); 

    } 
}
```

and converted into a Python program:

```
#############################
#  random number generation
#############################
m = 4294967296
a = 1664525
c = 1013904223
seed = 1

def NextInt():
    global seed
    seed = (((a * seed + c) % m))
    return seed

def NextInt2(min, max):
    temp = NextInt()
    ddd = temp / m
    return int((max - min) * ddd + min)

def NextDouble():
    temp = NextInt()
    return temp / m

def NextDouble2(min, max):
    temp = NextInt()
    fraction = temp / m
    return (max - min) * fraction + min  

#######################################
# Fermet's method of primality test
#######################################    
def Power(a, n, p): 
    res = 1; 
    a = a % p;  
    while (n > 0):
        if ((n and 1) == 1): 
            res = (res * a) % p; 

        n = n / 2;  
        a = (a * a) % p; 

    return res; 

def IsPrime(n, k): 
    if (n <= 1 or n == 4): 
        return False; 

    if (n <= 3):
        return True; 

    while (k > 0): 
        a = 2 + NextInt() % (n - 4);  

        if (Power(a, n - 1, n) != 1): 
            return False; 

        k = k-1; 

    return True;

#####################      
#    Main Program  
#####################    
k = 3; 

if(IsPrime(11, k)): 
    print(" true"); 
else:
    print(" false"); 

if(IsPrime(15, k)): 
    print(" true"); 
else:
    print(" false");
```

This Python program is always returning `False`.

Why?

Comment: `if ((n and 1) == 1):` is using logical AND. The Java code is using bitwise AND (`&`).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'int'`

Comment: You can't use bitwise operators on floats. Convert to int?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, n and 1 both are integers. So, what is going on here?

Comment: I believe `n = n / 2;` will convert `n` to float. Try `n = n // 2` for integer division.

Comment: Please update your question title. My suggestion would be ___Problem when converting 'Fermat's primality test'  from Java to Python___

Comment: Fermat's primality test sometimes gives the wrong results, like for the number 341.  I have a version that uses Fermat's test in addition with another test i created thats non probabilistic here: https://github.com/oppressionslayer/primalitytest